# Using NSString "drawInRect" with newlines

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

When I use drawInRect, it doesn't recognize a newline and just drops everything after the screen. The view looks like:

> First

But I expect it to look like:

> First
>
> Second

Here is the code:

```
        periodText = @"First\nSecond";
        
        periodStringSize = [periodText sizeWithFont:font];
        periodStringRect = CGRectMake(aPeriod.origin.x+boxWidth/2-periodStringSize.width/2, aPeriod.origin.y, periodStringSize.width, periodStringSize.height);
        
        [periodFontColor set];
        [periodText drawInRect:periodStringRect withFont:periodFont];
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? The code works perfectly fine for strings without newlines.

Comment: Have you confirmed your `periodStringRect` is tall enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `periodStringRect` is tall enough to display two lines.